# C# check if any letter in String A contains String B

Tags: c#

I have a String (String1) with text "HELLO".

Now I want to check if String2 has ANY letter of String1.
If yes, I want to remove that letter in String2. How can I do that?

Comment: Strings are arrays of characters, so you can start with `foreach (var character in text) {if (text2.Contains(character) {etc..}}`

Comment: Naive way is to iterate through each letter in string1 then iterate through each letter in string2 and do a logical check

Comment: Could the characters appear in any order? For example, if you had the strings "dfs" and "abf" you'd want to remove the f from one of them? (If they could only occur in the "same" position - e.g. "dfs" and "afb" you can do this more efficiently).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using *Linq*; to check if any characters of the `firstString` are in the `secondString`:

```
 bool result = firstString.Intersect(secondString).Any();
```

To remove `firstString` characters from the `secondString`:

```
 string result = string.Concat(secondString.Except(firstString));
```

**Edit**: There's a *side effect* of `Except`: it removes *duplicates* from the `secondString` as well, see Ivan Stoev's comment below. To preserve the duplicates

```
 HashSet<char> toRemove = new HashSet<char>(firstString);   
 string result = string.Concat(secondString.Where(c => !toRemove.Contains(c)));
```

Comment: Works fine! Thanks! :)

Comment: The second doesn't work. firstString = "bc", secondString = "abca", result="a" (should be "aa")

Comment: @Ivan Stoev: nice catch! Thank you!  I've overlooked the fact that`Except` turns `IEnumerable<T>` into *set* and thus drops duplicates. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Self Explanatory:

```
        string a = "HELLO";
        string b = "GOODBYE";
        foreach (char c in a.ToCharArray())
        {
            if (b.Contains(c)) { b = b.Replace(c.ToString(), string.Empty); }
        }
```

Output: b = "GDBY"

Answer (score 0):

Create Helper like below:

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<char, int>> IndexDistinct(IEnumerable<char> source)
{
    var D = new Dictionary<char, int>();
    foreach (var c in source)
    {
        D[c] = D.ContainsKey(c) ? (D[c] + 1) : 0;
        yield return Tuple.Create(c, D[c]);
    }
}
```

Now call helper method in a function like:

```
string removeMatch(string str1, string str2)
{
    return new string(
        IndexDistinct(str1)
            .Except(IndexDistinct(str2))
            .Select(x => x.Item1)
            .ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the shortest way

```
var str1 = "Hello World";
var str2 = "Hello Word Again";

var result = string.Joing("", str2.Except(str1));

Console.WriteLine(result); //Again
```